# Error while generating Angular component after upgrading from Angular 13 to 14 in nx workspace using `nx migrate`

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-workspace

Need help...

Not sure why I'm starting to get these kind of errors after upgrading angular 13 to 14 using `nx migrate`

I can't generate angular component.

Using `nx g c component-name`

```
InvalidInputOptions [Error]: Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"style":"scss","skipTests":true,"skipImport":true,"path":"libs/fisendo-web/staycation/ui/staycation-components/src/lib/components/property-content","project":"fisendo-web-staycation-ui-staycation-components","name":"component-name","displayBlock":false,"inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"Default","flat":false,"skipSelector":false,"type":"component","export":false}

Errors:

  Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(standalone).
    at MapSubscriber.project (***\***\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\schema-option-transform.js:30:27)
    at MapSubscriber._next (***\***\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:49:35)
    ...
    ...
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._next (***\***\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\throwIfEmpty.js:44:26) {
  errors: [
    {
      instancePath: '',
      schemaPath: '#/additionalProperties',
      keyword: 'additionalProperties',
      params: [Object],
      message: 'must NOT have additional properties'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I know it sounds weird, but have you tried `ng g component` or `ng generate component` already too? [There have been similar issues like this in the past](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/9869#issuecomment-1109522391)

Comment: same error appears in `ng generate component` and `ng generate pipe`

Comment: I am facing this problem too. I upgraded angular 12 to 14. But the terminal replied "Nothing to be done" after I typed "ng g c about"

Answer (score 0):

This is so weird, after I upgraded from `@angular/fire@7.2.1` to latest (v7.4.1) it seems that I can create components now.

I got the idea of upgrading `@angular/fire` from [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10676#issuecomment-1152149895).